# Using CSS to animate the fill of SVG path elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yh2jzoxa/). I have animated the drawing of a `path` element using `walkway.js` and it works great, but after the drawing is completed I would like to animate the fill of the `svg`'s path element. I have tried giving the path the following CSS:

```
path { 
transition: fill 2.0s linear !important;
}
```

and on the callback function (executed when the `.draw()` is completed) I change the value of the path's `fill` by applying the class `testClass` like so:

```
.testClass {
    fill:black;
}
```

This isn't working - the transition is not being applied and when the callback is called it instantly 'flicks' black-- no fade in at all. This same method has worked on plain html elements, not involved with SVGs. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it something to transition from, by adding `fill: white` to your path.

```
path {
    fill: white;
    transition: fill 2.0s !important;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yh2jzoxa/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can't transition fill from **nothing** to black.
Add original fill to `path`

```
path { 
    transition: fill 2.0s !important;
    fill: transparent;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/myst/yh2jzoxa/7/)