# Use CSS to animate the fill of an SVG along the path

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I've seen lots of questions and answers about how to do a full object animation of color like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307401/using-css-to-animate-the-fill-of-svg-path-elements). However, is it possible to animate a sharp, moving color block through the fill (interior of a path)? How would one go about animating an SVG like that?

Comment: If you use multiple gradient stops you can get sharp edges.

Comment: try to search on google.

Comment: I don't think anyone quite understands what you want.  Can you embed (or link) a picture?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple Javascript libraries that you can look into: [svgjs](http://svgjs.com/) or [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/)....Should point you in the right direction.

Just a quick piece of code to shw how snap would work. I will just give you a senario where you want to change the fill of an svg on hover.

```
<svg id="targetSvg" ...>
    <!-- path forming the upper shell -->
    <g>
    <path id="1" fill="#000" d="..."/>
    <path id="2" fill="#fff" d="..."/>
    <path id="3" fill="#000" d="..."/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Javascript

```
//select the svg you want to have the effect on
s = Snap("#targetSvg");

s.select("g").hover( isHover, idHoverOut );

function isHover() {
    this.selectAll('path').forEach( function( el ){
        el.attr({ class: 'fadeIn' })  } );
};

function isHoverOut() {
    this.selectAll('path').forEach( function( el ){
        el.attr({ class: 'fadeOut' })  } );
};
```

Css styles

```
.fadein {
   transition: fill 1s linear;
   fill:blue;
}

.fadeout {
   transition: fill 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I only meant to point the guy in the right direction. But do understand what you mean. Sometime trying to help someone ends up costing you more points that it should.

Comment: I understand that it is easy to animate color changes as fading the entire SVG or path to a different color, but how can you animate a color change along a path? Like, if you wanted to have a different color snake through the interior of a path.

Comment: [This](http://codepen.io/ghepting/pen/xnezB) is a codepen I came across when I was playing with svgs . This should help.